# How can I create data structure with multiple values in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm learning Swift and I'm wondering how can I create a data structure with multiple values and pass descriptions values from UITableViewController to another viewController? I have tried like this

```swift
   struct faculty {
        var name = String()
        var descriptions = (String)[]
   }
   let faculties = [name: "Faculties", description: ["Study1", "Study2"]]
```

I have successfully managed to list an array ["Test1", "Test2"] in tableView.

Comment: The short-hand for an Array type in Swift is `[String]` (for an array of strings), which is just short for `Array<String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues

- An empty string array is `[String]()`.
- `description` is not equal to `descriptions`.
- An instance must be created with `Type(parameter1:parameter2:)`.
- And structs are supposed to be named with starting capital letter.

---

```
struct Faculty {
     var name = String()
     var descriptions = [String]()
}

let faculties = [Faculty(name: "Faculties", descriptions: ["Study1", "Study2"])]
```

However default values are not needed. This is also valid

```
struct Faculty {
     let name : String
     var descriptions : [String]
}
```